# Using JAX-RS / Jersey with Freemarker templates

Tags: java, templates, jersey, freemarker, jax-rs

There are examples on the web showing how to use the JAX-RS implementation [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/) with custom template engines like [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.org/). But these examples are looking a bit [improvised](http://biddlog.blogspot.com/2010/06/jersey-jax-rs-and-freemarker.html) or [dated](http://github.com/cwinters/jersey-freemarker/blob/master/src/com/cwinters/jersey/FreemarkerTemplateProvider.java). There is also one [example relying only on JAX-RS](http://blogs.citytechinc.com/sjohnson/?p=32) and not Jersey specific classes. Is there a mature `ViewProcessor` implementation for FreeMarker or do I have to write my own?

Answer (score 2):

This example here doesn't use Sun specific stuff, it uses standard jax-rs constructs...

http://blogs.citytechinc.com/sjohnson/?p=32

Comment: the link is dead